# How do I assign sort a dataset and assign the order value?

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by

I have a database that is sorted based on the patient_id and appointment_date as below:
[image]

How do I add a new column for the order of appointment to make the table look like below in sqlite3?

[image]

Thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `row_number()` window function:

```
select *,
  row_number() over (partition by patient_id order by appointment_date) [order]
from tablename
order by patient_id, appointment_date
```

But you will have to change the format of your dates to `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm` so they are comparable.